# Use multiple times one component in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I created an application where i have an select. I want to use this Select many times but i can't set it properly to be universal for every situation.

link to my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hide-already-selected-ant-design-demo-2h7po

Now, how you can see, i used it 3  times in my First component, but if i select data in one select and after that in second, the second select overrides previous, and so on. I want to save data for every select, and to have the possibility to use the state from each select. How to do this?

Comment: sandbox shared isn't working...could you please check?

Comment: UniversalSelect.js in sand box is empty and Sandbox is not working. Can you please update it ?